PySpark sum multiple columns row by row
I work in pySpark. I have 3 datasets like below (sometimes more than 3)
aa1=dfActivity.filter((f.col("UserID") == 514)).select('UserID','DoctorID','Department','Company','scoreHrs','MonthNumber','YearNumber','PeriodID')
aa2=dfCalories.filter((f.col("UserID") == 514)).select('UserID','DoctorID','Department','Company','score','MonthNumber','YearNumber','PeriodID') 
aa3=dfWHO5.filter((f.col("UserID") == 514)).select('UserID','DoctorID','Department','Company','score','MonthNumber','YearNumber','PeriodID')

I need to sum the columns "scoreHrs"+"score"+"score" from aa1, aa2 and aa3 respectively row by row and assign the value to a new dataframe.
How can this be done?

Assuming you only need the newly created sum column in your new dataframe, here is my answer:
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([["x",1],["x",2],["x",3],["x",4],["x",5],\
                            ["x",6]], ["col1", "scorehrs"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([["x",22],["x",22],["x",23],["x",24],["x",25],\
["x",26]], ["col1", "score"])
df3 = spark.createDataFrame([["x",31],["x",32],["x",33],["x",34],["x",35],\
["x",36]], ["col1", "score"])


w1=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
list_dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
new_dfs=[]

for idx,df in enumerate(list_dfs):
    
    df=df.withColumn("row",row_number().over(w1))
    if "score" in df.columns:
       df=df.withColumnRenamed("score","score_"+str(idx))
    new_dfs.append(df)

joined_df =new_dfs[0]
for df in new_dfs[1:]:
    joined_df=joined_df.join(df,on="row",how="inner")
joined_df=joined_df.withColumn("sum",expr("score_1 + score_2 + scorehrs")).select("sum")
joined_df.show()

